# show AChartEngine inside relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, achartengine

I am going to have a page with two or three relative layout. One of them must be specifically for including Line chart. For showing line chart, I use AChartEngine. I wanna know how relative layout can hold AChartEngine?

If not possible, please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show a graph in AchartEngine as part of the whole screen , you need `GraphicalView`

```
    private GraphicalView mChartView;
    //...
    mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
    RelativeLayout rlLayout=...;
    rlLayout.addView(mChartView);
```